# Escaping special chars in Haskell

Tags: haskell

How to escape special characters in String / Text with Haskell? Preferred approach is to use standard solutions ("standard" functions, libraries). So,

```
"aaa\nbbb\r" must be transformed to "aaa\\nbbb\\r"
```

I found only JSONb library which is totally outdated and depends on old ByteString, so I can't build it. Also there is MissingH but it's collection of anything-anything. Is any standard solution for it, it looks very useful?

Comment: Please, don't downvote if you DONT KNOW how to escape character in Haskell. As I see, no way to do it without to reinvent the wheel with serial replace's. Am I right?

Comment: There's more than one style of escaping - what will be consuming your escaped strings?  (If you want the escaping style that Haskell source code uses, just using `show` on the string would work.)

Comment: and resulting string must be stripped from quote-symbols

Comment: You have to define "special characters" (everybody has a different idea about what's special), and then define how you want to escape what (is `\e` a valid escape for the ASCII escape character?) And no, yoy are not right about serial replaces. That's neither the fastest method nor the easiest to implement.

Comment: There are several possible escape methods. Do you need any one of them in particular, or is any one fine, as long as it produces printable chars? `show`, as already suggested, could be enough (and you can strip the outermost quotes, if you do not want them).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`show` will take an arbitrary `String` and serialize it to only printable 7-bit-safe characters.

```
> show "aaa\nbbb\r"
"\"aaa\\nbbb\\r\""
```

The first and last characters will always be quotation marks, so you can safely drop the first and last characters if you prefer not to have this part of the standard serialization for some reason.

Comment: Is there an easy way to drop those characters?

Comment: @aurelia `init . tail`